# Comparing two values in a structfield of a column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Column where each row is a StructField. I want to get max of two values in the StructField.

I tried this

```py
trends_df = trends_df.withColumn("importance_score", max(col("avg_total")["max"]["agg_importance"], col("avg_total")["min"]["agg_importance"], key=max_key))
```

But it throws this error

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I am now getting it done with UDFs

```py
max_key = lambda x: x if x else float("-inf")
_get_max_udf = udf(lambda x, y: max(x,y, key=max_key), FloatType())
trends_df = trends_df.withColumn("importance_score", _get_max_udf(col("avg_total")["max"]["agg_importance"], col("avg_total")["min"]["agg_importance"]))
```

This works, but I want to know if there a way I can avoid using the udf and get it done with just spark.

Edit:
This is the result of `trends_df.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- avg_total: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- max: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- avg_percent: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- max_index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- max_val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- total_percent: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- total_val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- min: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- avg_percent: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- min_index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- min_val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- total_percent: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- total_val: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `trends_df.printSchema` to your question? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Added the schema @Koedlt

Comment: can you flatten this and then try to get the max value. flatten code```col_name.*```

Comment: I don't see `agg_importance` in the print schema response that was included

Comment: Could the `greatest` function work for you? 
`trends_df = trends_df.withColumn("importance_score", greatest(col("avg_total")["max"]["agg_importance"], col("avg_total")["min"]["agg_importance"]))`
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest

Comment: Please show sample input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding an answer from the comments to highlight it.*

As answered by @smurphy I used the `greatest` function

```py
trends_df = trends_df.withColumn("importance_score", greatest(col("avg_total")["max"]["agg_importance"], col("avg_total")["min"]["agg_importance"]))
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest